# Logic Question regarding quantifiers

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, logic, ring-theory, quantifiers

If I said $\forall h \neq 0$ $\exists$ t
I know that this can be translated into for any given t there exists, but does t have to depend on h? I think not, but can someone tell me if I'm correct?

For instance, if I wanted to prove every finite integral domain is a field, I can say that I have a non-repeating set which contains all the elements of the integral domain ${a_1,a_2,a_3....,a_n}$ for some n, then multiply every element by a non-element and so ${ca_1,ca_2...,ca_n}$ is the same finite integral domain and since it is a ring with unity there exists a $1\in$ R, so c$a_i$ $=$ $1$ and so there exists an inverse, however this inverse does not necessarily depend on $a_m$. May someone please explain?

The definition of a field is a commutative ring such that $\forall a\neq$ 0 in R $\exists$ $a^{-1}$ in R such that $aa^{-1}$ $=$ $1$.

Comment: No, $∀ h\exists t$ just states exactly "for every h there exists t...", because $t$ came after the $h$ it can depend on $h$, but not necessarily

Comment: @Holo what would be an example of a true mathematical proposition in which t comes after h but does not depend on it? And how would you prove it?

Comment: $∀h ∃t (t=t)$ is a trivial one

Comment: As an aside, your example can only be expressed in first-order logic if $n$ is a fixed constant. You can't state the claim that every finite integral domain is a field in the first-order language of a ring.